# Fetching by associative array

Tags: php, sql

If you fetch the following data via an associative array in php:

```
SELECT thread.id, thread.title, thread.content, author.username, author.id
FROM thread INNER JOIN author
ON author_id = author.id
```

How can you differentiate between author.id and thread.id?

```
$threads = select_Query('SELECT thread.id, thread.title, thread.content, author.username, author.id
                         FROM thread INNER JOIN author
                         ON author_id = author.id', $link);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use column aliases to resolve column name ambiguities:

```
SELECT thread.id AS t_id, thread.title, thread.content, author.username, author.id AS a_id
FROM thread INNER JOIN author
ON author_id = author.id
```

Then reference the aliases in your PHP array, as `$row['t_id']` and `$row['a_id']` respectively.